# Deserialize JSon to Payload<List<Post>> using JsonSerializer.Deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following classes:

```
public class Post {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
}  

public class Payload<T> {
  public IList<Error> Errors { get; private set; }
  public T Result { get; private set; }
}
```

And I have the following Json:

```
{
  "result": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "Post 1" },
    { "id": 2, "title": "Post 2" }
  ]
}
```

I tried to parse this Json to `Payload<List<Post>>` using:

```
Payload<List<Post>> payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Payload<List<Post>>>(json);
```

However, the field `payload.Result` is null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json I found that when you deserialize your item it should look like the following;

```
public class Result
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public IList<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

But I see this in addition to these in your code;

```
  public T Result { get; private set; }
```

Maybe this is not a problem since the setter is not public, but I still think it would be more understandable to say JsonIgnore.

If you are wondering what object your Json will transform after deserialization, you can look [here](https://www.jsonutils.com/).

Comment: The problem was using the private set. I just solved it. Thank you for the help.